# Бой в браузерной игре

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать пвп бой в браузерной игре. Ну, в общем, я знаю, как это сделать, хочу просто уточнить некие нюансы:

1. Создаем таблицу пвп, в ней ставим жизни мои и врага, атака мой и врага
2. Создаем файлик "Вызова на бой", в ней мы заносим имя противника и мое с всеми данными (если можно, то подскажите код)
3. Создаем файлик там, где я нападаю
4. Создаем файлик там, где меня атакуют

Вот так я думаю это сделать, если не правильно, можете, пожалуйста, подправить =) Заранее спасибо...

Comment: У столь абсрактного вопроса не может быть ответов вида "правильно" "не правильно". Во всяком случае я не совсем понимаю как вы будут связывать происходящие в этих файлах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуем поэксперементировать, по крайней мере я сделал бы так!
Создаем таблицу боя.

1. Создаем запись вызова на бой, содержащую id пользователя и id того кого вызываем.
2. Если отклоняет, удаляем запись. Принимает (смотрим внизу). Удаляем запись. Создаем таблицу атаки:
3. Создаем 2 для юзеров записи xp, силы, навыков и что еще придумаем.
4. Извлекаем параметры, шаманим над принципом кто-кого ударил (можно логировать все в одну таблицу логов боя), вычитаем у каждого кто сколько урона нанес, что применил, как
   ударил.
5. Сравниваем xp, если 0, выводим результат победителю и проигравшему, удаляем записи из таблицы атаки, чистим логи, плюсуем опыт, разного рода бонусы.

Причем можно сделать так, что атаковать можно за определенный момент времени, (30 сек. для каждого), либо независимо друг от друга. Так-же всякие прибамбасы включая хил, уклонение, и т.д и т.п. Ну а там что душе угодно:) в принципе как-то так, причем нужно подумать над каждым принципом отдельно и поподробнее...

P.S готов ловить какахи)))

P.P.S комменте внизу, додумаем вместе...

Comment: А зачем таблицы? Открываем сессию. Вгоняем все данные обоих игроков. Проводим весь поединок внутри сессии. По окончанию поединка - изменившиеся параметры забрасываются в БД. Опционально сохраняется статический лог и швыряется в архив. Сессия удяляется.

Если пользователь разлогинился, то при залогине его зашвырнёт в поединок. Если поединок уже окончен - его просто зашвырнёт в игру.

Этот вариант разгрузит базу, если предположить, что поединков будет минимум несколько десятков в минуту.

Comment: ок. пускай два юзера попали в таблицы. А дальше? Один сделал ход и второй юзер тоже сделал ход. Кто будет вычитывать все шансы, урон, остаток здоровья и т.д. И как понять что уже сделан ход кем-то. И как вернуть новые данные юзеру, который сделал ход первым, если вычитывать будет последний походивший?